# why do I get only 3 return values by using a json link:

Tags: php, json

there should be many more return values?

```
print_r($data);
```

shows that there is much more to be displayed.
Thanks for any hints,

Stefan

```
<?php 
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getorderbook?market=BTC-DOGE&type=sell'),TRUE);
//print_r($data);
$ncount = COUNT( $data );
for($i=0;$i<$ncount;$i++){
echo $data['result'][$i]['Quantity'] .'<br />';
}
?>
```

Comment: If you `var_dump(count($data));` what is the value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$ncount` should be the `count()` of `$data['result'];`

Try this:

```
<?php 
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getorderbook?market=BTC-DOGE&type=sell'),TRUE);

$ncount = count($data['result']);
for($i=0;$i<$ncount;$i++){
    echo $data['result'][$i]['Quantity'] .'<br />';
}
?>
```

Comment: No problem, if the answer solved it for you, feel free to mark it correct, so future people won't have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

While not a definite answer, you're running `count` on `$data`, but then displaying `$data['result']`. So if the root array only contains 3 values, you'll only go through the loop 3 times. Instead, try a `foreach`:

```
foreach ($data['result'] as $result){
    echo $result['Quantity'] .'<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are making things WAY too difficult .. Set `result` to `data['result']` and iterate through that

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getorderbook?market=BTC-DOGE&type=sell'),TRUE);


$result = $data['result'];

foreach($result as $item){
    echo $item['Quantity'] . '<br />';
}



?>
```